# Dojo's array.some isn't parsing the array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dojo

```
array.some(resourceList, function (resource) {   
    //stuff happens
}, this);
```

resourceList is [Object{...}]
resource - doesn't exist
//stuff happens doesn't happen

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by "parse"? You're passing an array object, not a JSON string or so?

Comment: Is resourceList realy an array or is it a Store you tried to search?